# How to decide which action to run by post or get on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form page called "refund.html.erb"

let user to complete a form and then send it.

in my routes

```
  get 'refund' => 'orders#refund'
  post 'refund' => 'orders#refund'
```

in my controller

```
  def refund
      apply_refund_to_gdocs
    respond_to  do |format|
      format.html{}
    end
  end
```

the apply_refund_to_gdocs defined in helper,
but now when I load the form page , it will call apply_refund_to_gdocs.
But I only want apply_refund_to_gdocs called when user send the form.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best way is to separate this method in two, since it is intended for two different things. I'd go with:

```
get 'refund' => 'orders#refund', as: :refund
post 'refund' => 'orders#do_refund', as: :do_refund
```

and then in the controller you have

```
def refund
  # your original 'GET' stuff
  render 'refund'
end

def do_refund
  # your post stuff
  # render 'refund' or redirect 
end
```

Notice that if you render the view in `do_refund` instead of redirecting to `refund_path` a refresh in the browser window will trigger the post action again. So is better to render only when there are form errors you want the user to correct, otherwise redirect.

But if you want to stay with a single method you can check the request in the controller. Something like:

```
def refund
  if request.post?
    #do post stuff
  else
    # do get stuff
  end
end
```